# In D3, Bar graph's text labels are not updated after the inclusion of additional data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am making a bar graph. As a user loads the page, they will see a bar graph with 20 bars in total, and each bar comes with a label indicating the numerical value the bar represents (as shown below).

[image]

If the user clicks on a line of text on top of the graph, the graph will update to include two additional randomly generated bars. For some reason, I cannot get the graph to also update the labels for the new bars. For example, after one click on the text, I get something shown below:

[image]

The relevant code is below, and the complete code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/55DLc/9/

```
var texts = svg.selectAll("text").data(dataset);
texts.enter()
     .append("text")
     .text(function(d){ return d; })
     .attr("x", w - padding)
     .attr("y", function( d ){return yScale( d ) - 2;})
     .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
     .attr("fill", "red");
texts.transition()
     .duration(500)
     .text(function(d){return d;})
     .attr("x", function(d, i){return xScale( i ) + xScale.rangeBand()/2;})
     .attr("y", function( d ){return yScale( d ) - 2;})
     .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
     .attr("fill", "red");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your update, this line:

```
var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
               .data(dataset);
```

is not only selecting your text labels on top of the bars but it also selecting the text labels that are part of the axis.

Easy fix is to assign a unique class to your text labels and select on that to update them.

Here's it all fixed up:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>D3 Page Template</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
 .axis path,
 .axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
 }
 .axis text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  fill: black;
  font-size: 13px;
 }
     div.bar {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20px;
        background-color: teal;
    }
</style>
        </head>
        <body>
         <p>Click on this text to update the chart</p>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    
    w = 600, h = 500, padding = 30;
    var dataset = [ 5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
        11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];
    var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
                .rangeRoundBands([padding, w - padding], 0.05);
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([ 0,
                     d3.max(dataset)])
                .range([ h - padding, padding ]);    
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
          .scale( xScale )
          .orient("bottom")
          .ticks( 10 );
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
          .scale( yScale )
          .orient("left");
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);
    svg.selectAll("rect")
          .data(dataset)
       .enter()
       .append("rect")
       .transition()
       .delay(function(d, i){
         return i * 100;
        })
       .duration(500)
       .attr("x", function(d, i){
         return xScale(i)
       })
       .attr("y", function( d ){
         return yScale( d );
       })
       .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
       .attr("height", function(d){
         return  h - yScale( d ) - padding - 1;
       })
          .attr("fill", function( d ){
         return "rgb(150, 220, " + (d * 10) + ")";
       });
    svg.selectAll("text")
       .data(dataset)
       .enter()
       .append("text")
       .attr("class","myLabels")
       .transition()
        .delay(function(d, i){
          return i * 100;
         })
          .text(function(d){
         return d;
       })
       .attr("x", function(d, i){
         return xScale( i ) + xScale.rangeBand()/2;
       })
       .attr("y", function( d ){
         return  yScale( d ) - 2;
       })
       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
       .attr("fill", "red");

    svg.append("g")
       .attr("class", "x axis")
       .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (h - padding) + ")")
       .call(xAxis);
    svg.append("g")
       .attr("class", "y axis")
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + (padding) + ", 0)")
       .call(yAxis);

    d3.select("p")
      .on("click", function(){
       for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++ ){
        var newNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*25 );
        dataset.push( newNumber );
       }

    xScale.domain(d3.range(dataset.length));

    yScale.domain([ 0, d3.max(dataset)]);    
    
    var bars = svg.selectAll("rect")
       .data(dataset);

       bars.enter()
       .append("rect")
       .attr("x", w - padding)
       .attr("y", function( d ){
         return yScale( d ) ;
        })
       .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
       .attr("height", function(d){
         return  h - yScale( d ) - padding;
       })
       .attr("fill", function( d ){
         return "rgb(150, 220, " + (d * 10) + ")";
       })
    bars.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("x", function(d, i){
         return xScale( i );
        })
        .attr("y", function( d ){
         return yScale( d );
        })
        .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
        .attr("height", function(d){
         return  h - yScale( d ) - padding  - 1;
        });
       
       
       
       var texts = svg.selectAll(".myLabels")
                .data(dataset);
       texts.enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("class","myLabels")
      .text(function(d){ return d; })
      .attr("x", w - padding)
      .attr("y", function( d ){
          return yScale( d ) - 2;
         })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("fill", "red");

       texts.transition()
            .duration(500)
         .text(function(d){
          return d;
        })
      .attr("x", function(d, i){
          return xScale( i ) + xScale.rangeBand()/2;
      })
      .attr("y", function( d ){
          return yScale( d ) - 2;
          })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("fill", "red");
      
    svg.select( ".x.axis")
       .transition()
       .duration(1000)
       .call(xAxis);
        svg.select( ".y.axis")
       .transition()
       .duration(1000)
       .call(yAxis);
           
      });


            </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! It did exactly what I wanted.